# "If" statement in php. I want to display a phrase in woocommerce for only certain product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

Hello This is my first post on stackoverflow and I'm new to webdesign so I really appreciate any help!

I'm trying to have "per sq ft" appear after the price in only some products in my woocommerce store.

I have searched and tried just about every combination of the following code I can think of but no luck.

```
<?php if ( $product_cat == "Hardwood" )
    echo "per sq ft"; 
?>
```

I found the file to put it in but can't get it to work.

Bonus points if you can help me do this for mulitipal categories.  I can't figure out if I would just keep making "if" statements for each differnt result I want or if I need "else" statements too?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried echo'ing $product_cat to see what's actually set when comparing it to the string?

Comment: Hello Karl, I've tried <?php echo $product_cat ?> and a few variation but that didn't work. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple possibilities you are better off using a switch statement.  However, why it doesn't work i cannot answer because you haven't said why its broken and there isn't nearly enough code there to say what is wrong. One random guess could be a case sensitive string ?  if $product_cat is "hardwood" instead of "Hardwood" it wouldn't match.

```
<?php
    switch(strtolower($product_cat))
    {
        case "hardwood":
            echo "per sq ft";
            break;
         case "plastic":
            echo "stuff";
            break;
        default:
             echo "default";
             break;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you Lonewolf217,  I tried your code but still no luck.  The only thing that shows up is the "default".  I tried Hardwood and hardwood and parent categories and single categories and still no luck.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how to see if it is broken. I've run the google chrome's inspect element and there was nothing in the console tab.

Comment: console tab is not going to show php errors.  if you are hitting 'default' every time here then as another suggestion already mentioned, echo $product_cat to see what the value actually is.  the brackets are useful to see if there are trailing spaces that you need to trim() off

echo "PRODUCTCAT: [$product_cat]";

Comment: Thanks @DanielLisik and lonewolf217, it's returning as: "PRODUCTCAT: []". So I must not be calling the right information. I made a work around by just adding this code to call for a the cat desc. It's not what I wanted but works well enough since Im in over my head with coding and you have all been so helpful. Thanks again!   <?php 
 global $post;
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',);
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat', $args);
    $count = count($terms); 
    if ($count > 0) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            echo $term->description;}}
?>

Comment: if you want more help, show code for how $product_cat is defined or assigned

Answer (score 0):

You need to have brackets when you write `if` statements, like this:

```
if ($something == 'foo') {
   // Do something
} else if ($something == 'foofoo') {
   // Do something else
}
```

or, if you don't want to use brackets, you could write like this:

```
if ($something == 'foo'):
   // Do something
else if ($something == 'foofoo'):
   // Do something else
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks @daniel, I've tried both those styles too.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the way I'm calling for the $product_cat.

Comment: If you try this code: `echo $product_cat;` and get no result, you have assigned the value you wan't to examine to the wrong variable. Make sure it really is `$product_cat` holding the information you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce has ways of testing the type of page you are viewing. For product categories you can use:

`if (is_product_category( 'hardwood' )) {echo 'per sq ft';}`

Use that line where you want "per sq ft" to appear.

Here's the link to all the Woocommerce conditional tags: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/

Here's the link to the Woocommerce template structure and how to overide the default layout within your theme:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/